# How to make UIButton overlapping UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have a scrollview and I need UIbutton/label overlapping it as in example ("Close")
[image]

I added UIButton to storyboard above my scrollView and make constraints to the top of the superView:
[image]

But the button is still invisible on simulator.

Comment: change your view hierarchy, drop button bellow sv, (refer your image in last.)

Comment: @dahiya_boy It worked, but it's not possible to click on it (Touch up inside event doesn't happen)